# IPhone Web Design Preview

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I've been using Safari on Windows and the iBBDemo Blackbaud iPhone Browser Simulator to emulate an iPhone but I have noticed that Safari does not render form elements using the default control styles. Safari on iPhone supplies default control styles that are specific to iPhone. This means my web forms look nothing like they do on an actual iPhone.

Are there any style sheets or iPhone Web Design Tool Kits that will style the form elements exactly as they should appear? Or is there an online service that provides screenshots of how a web page looks on an iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mac, then the easiest way is to use the iPhone Simulator. It might not be suitable for your purposes, though.

There are a lot of things which you'd need to do to get the rendering right (there are a lot of rounded rects, and the user can scale the page to an arbitrary size, and strange things sometimes happen when you rotate the device).